# How to load Joomla framework in external file including the template?

Tags: joomla-api, joomla-framework-1.x

We can load Joomla framework in external file via 
http://docs.joomla.org/Framework_Compatibility

```
// Define JRequest::clean to protect our variables!
define('_JREQUEST_NO_CLEAN', 1); 

// basic to make J! happy
define('_JEXEC', 1); //make j! happy
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Load up the standard stuff for testing
require_once JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php';
```

but is there a way to include the default frontend template  ?

Someone has already suggested this but it does not work 
http://westernstudios.net/tutorials/page/joomla-load-template-in-external-file

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define('JPATH_BASE',str_replace(basename(dirname(__FILE__)),"",dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe              = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$config                 = JFactory::getConfig();
$config->set('live_site','http://localhost/test/');// for js and css links
$mainframe->initialise();
$mainframe->route();
$mainframe->render();
echo $mainframe;
```

ok this one works

Comment: Ahh you were referring to the API, nott he framework. Wasn't aware :)

Comment: yes , API in external file